# wso2 governance registry build fail

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

i'm trying to build wso2 governance registry by src files with maven 3, but after many retries i'm stuck too.
I had dowload all required libraries, and fixed all duplicate child in pom files, but whem i'm trying to build i obtain this error.

```
"[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.
2-beta-5:attached (dist) on project axis2-kernel: Failed to create assembly: Err
or creating assembly archive docs: You must set at least one file. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]"
```

and previously

```
"[FATAL] Non-readable POM C:\greg\wso2greg-4.1.1-src\dependencies\axis2\1.6.1-wso2v1\modules\pom.xml: C:\greg\wso2greg-4.1.1-src\dependencies\axis2\1.6.1-wso2v1\modules\pom.xml (Impossibile trovare il file specificato) @ 
 for project  at C:\greg\wso2greg-4.1.1-src\dependencies\axis2\1.6.1-wso2v1\modules\pom.xml for project  at C:\greg\wso2greg-4.1.1-src\dependencies\axis2\1.6.1-wso2v1\modules\pom.xml"
```

I'm trying to build with maven 2 but, even if console output message shows "BUILD SUCCEFFULL" i can found bin folder and relative wso2server.bat file.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Are you trying to build greg from greg root ??

Comment: Why you want to build it by yourself instead of using binary provided by WSO2?

Answer (score 0):

Please clone below repos and run an `mvn clean install -e` on each and everyone accordingly.

- https://github.com/wso2/carbon4-kernel.git
- https://github.com/wso2/carbon-registry.git
- https://github.com/wso2/carbon-governance.git
- https://github.com/wso2/carbon-governance-extensions.git
- https://github.com/wso2/carbon-store

Then build G-Reg from the source!

Note: Current G-Reg developer snapshot :https://github.com/wso2/product-greg.git