# Source code of WSO2 GREG 4.6

Tags: wso2, soa, wso2-governance-registry

I'm looking for the source code os WSO2 Registry 4.6. I have installed the binaries but I have not been able to find the sources.

Is the source code available?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Governance Registry related sources available in [ckunk 2](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk02/) tag. If you building product from the source, Please refer "[Building from Source](http://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance460/Building+from+Source)" guide.

Answer (score 0):

Find the wso2 Governance Registry source from [here](https://github.com/wso2/product-greg).

Note: make sure you follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295653/wso2-governance-registry-build-fail/26397930#26397930) as well.