# wso2reg 4.6: detailed "Build from source"

Tags: svn, wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I am new with SVN and wso2reg product too. I don't understand the "Build from source" at all. I' looking for more detailed (step by step) example how I can get all Java projects to modify, assembly and deploy products.

I've seen this topic: [Source code of WSO2 GREG 4.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19923292/source-code-of-wso2-greg-4-6). But, Which tag we have to choose? Downloading .../turing-chunk02 tagxxx do I get all artifacts that I need for assembly and deploy the wso2reg? Do I need download kernel, platform and orbit separately? Which version of each one?. Is there any specific order to build kernel, platform, orbit and greg?

Thanks in advance, Diego

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't build WSO2 source code before/or not build recently, first you have to build

1.Orbit ([here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/orbit/tags/4.2.0/))
2.Kernel ([here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/tags/4.2.0/))

in the order.

After building above you can start building platform. GREG 4.6 is in chunk3. So you have to build all chunks upto chunk3. So build

3.chunk1 ([here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk01/))
4.chunk2 ([here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk02/))
5.chunk3 ([here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk03/))

Thanks,
Malintha Adikari

Answer (score 0):

Use git, WSO2 recently moved to git. Please clone below repos and run a `mvn clean install -e` on each and every one accordingly.

- https://github.com/wso2/carbon4-kernel.git
- https://github.com/wso2/carbon-registry.git
- https://github.com/wso2/carbon-governance.git
- https://github.com/wso2/carbon-governance-extensions.git
- https://github.com/wso2/carbon-store

Then build greg from source!

Note: Current greg developer snapshot :https://github.com/wso2/product-greg.git